# Preprocessor directive cannot be put in AND in C#

Tags: c#, preprocessor-directive, multi-project

I need to put some code under a preprocessor directive.
such directives can be defined in different projects.

My situation is the following:

File **Constants.cs** (which is in project Proj1Dll.csproj)

```
#define DEV
... rest of the code
```

File **Page1.cs** (which is in project MainProj.csproj, which references Proj1Dll)

```
#define SHOW_BTN

...

#if (DEV && SHOW_BTN)
  public static void Foo()
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("Both DEV and SHOW_BTN directives are defined");
  }
#endif
```

Such configuration is not working, in the sense that method Foo() is not part of the compilation.

If I check instead `#if (DEBUG && SHOW_BTN)` everything is fine.

Is there a way to deal with such directives when they are defined in different projects?

Comment: #define DEV in a *.h file and include it in both *.cs files.

Comment: @FrankMerrow how do you suggest to "include" in C# files?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, you can go to the Project Properties, and under the Build tab, you will see 'Conditional compilation symbols'

Put your synbols in here and they will be recognised **project wide**.

In your example you would put just    DEV   if you wanted more than one, separate them with semicolon e.g.    DEV;SHOW_BTN

If you want something to be solution wide and need only one symbol you can use the configuration manager to create a new configuration specifically for this build and call it what you like - this then gives you the same effect.
(It's why in your example DEBUG works)

Hope that helps.

Comment: OP is asking about reading a compilation symbol defined in a separate project, not just a separate file.

Comment: Ah ok, I read that as trying to find a way to make a directive available to multiple files.

Comment: I am trying to have different #define in different files across multiple projects. and I would like to understand how the availability of those #define (in code) work (e.g. if I #define a symbol in my MainProj , can I see it in Proj1Dll, which is just a dependency?)

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to have the symbols available in multiple files without declaring it in those multiple files other than the method I described in my answer for project wide symbols.  I've updated my answer to show how you could aso use configurations to provide a single, solution wide symbol.